# StorageFolder not getting any data back with get folders async

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, file-access

I followed a Microsoft example on how to access folders that were selected with a folder picker. After doing this I wanted to get all the paths of the sub folders within the selected top folder. I don't get any results however.

Code:

```
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
folderPicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.List;
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

if (folder != null)
{
    Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("GameFilesToken", folder);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(folder.Path);

    await FileManagementHelper.getFolders(folder.Path);
}

public static async Task<Queue<string>> getFolders(String TopLevel)
{
    var Folder = await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("GameFilesToken");

    var queryResults = Folder.CreateFolderQuery();
    var folderList = await queryResults.GetFoldersAsync();

    return new Queue<string>();
}
```

`QueryResults` gives me access to a folder, the same folder that I use originally. 
`FolderList` gives me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FolderList gives me nothing.

Your getting `folderList` code snippet can work well, `folderList` object do has values if the selected folder have sub folders. Please update your `getfolders` method to check the `folderList` by code as follows:

```
   var Folder = await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("GameFilesToken");
   var queryResults = Folder.CreateFolderQuery();
   var folderList = await queryResults.GetFoldersAsync();
   foreach (StorageFolder folder in  folderList )
   {
       Debug.WriteLine(folder.Path); 
   }
```

> I wanted to get all the paths of the sub folders within the selected top folder. I don't get any results however.

Actually, you can just use [StorageFolder.GetFoldersAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227280.aspx) method to get all sub folders for the selected top folder object, there is no need to use [CreateFolderQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227261.aspx) method if you want to list all. Code as follows:

```
private async void btngetfolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
    folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    folderPicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.List;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

    if (folder != null)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folderList = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
        foreach (StorageFolder subfolder in folderList)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("subfolder path:" + subfolder.Path);
        } 
    }
}
```

More details please reference the [FolderEnumeration](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FolderEnumeration) official sample.

Update:
If you want to get all sub folders include descendants sub folders, you need to set [QueryOptions.FolderDepth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.queryoptions.folderdepth.aspx) to deep. Code as follows:

```
 var Folder = await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("GameFilesToken");
 QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions();
 options.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
 var queryResults = Folder.CreateFolderQueryWithOptions(options);    
 var folderList = await queryResults.GetFoldersAsync();

 foreach (StorageFolder folder in  folderList )
 {
     Debug.WriteLine(folder.Path); 
 }
```

Comment: I understand my problem, the only thing is I need to get all directories under the top level. So like for example, TopLevel\, TopLevel\Folder1, TopLevel\Folder2, TopLevel\Folder1\SubFolder1

Comment: @BaileyMiller in that case, you need to set [FolderDepth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.queryoptions.folderdepth.aspx) property to deep. Details please see my updated answer.